# How can I print a webpage with code snippets entirely?

Tags: pdf, html, wkhtmltopdf

I want to print a web page https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-first-hibernate-application into a pdf file.

1. I am using `wkhtmltopdf` with various argument to
   `--javascript-delay` option, and with or without
   `--no-stop-slow-script`. For example

   ```
   wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 3000 https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-first-hibernate-application  app.pdf
   ```

   but it seems to take forever to finish running. I add
   `--debug-javascript` and the output information is

   ```
   Warning: :1 Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-4699858549023382&output=html&h=280&slotname=5592503653&adk=1365123429&adf=1932081468&w=336&lmt=1515359967&loeid=38893312&format=336x280&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.javatpoint.com%2Fsteps-to-create-first-hibernate-application&ea=0&flash=0&wgl=0&adsid=NT&dt=1515341967388&bpp=3&fdt=253&idt=262&shv=r20180102&cbv=r20170110&saldr=aa&prev_fmts=160x600%2C320x100%2C320x100&correlator=6433104240641&frm=20&ga_vid=1641940297.1515341967&ga_sid=1515341967&ga_hid=50326500&ga_fc=1&pv=1&icsg=2&nhd=1&dssz=2&mdo=0&mso=0&u_tz=-300&u_his=1&u_java=0&u_h=768&u_w=1366&u_ah=768&u_aw=1366&u_cd=32&u_nplug=0&u_nmime=0&adx=10&ady=4761&biw=0&bih=0&abxe=1&eid=38893302%2C21061122%2C191880502%2C41667001&oid=3&nmo=1&rx=0&eae=4&fc=16&brdim=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1366%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0&vis=0&rsz=%7C%7CeEbr%7C&abl=CS&ppjl=u&pfx=0&fu=1040&bc=1&ifi=4&dtd=283. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

   Warning: :1 Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-4699858549023382&output=html&h=280&slotname=5592503653&adk=1365123429&adf=1932081468&w=336&lmt=1515359967&loeid=38893312&format=336x280&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.javatpoint.com%2Fsteps-to-create-first-hibernate-application&ea=0&flash=0&wgl=0&adsid=NT&dt=1515341967388&bpp=3&fdt=253&idt=262&shv=r20180102&cbv=r20170110&saldr=aa&prev_fmts=160x600%2C320x100%2C320x100&correlator=6433104240641&frm=20&ga_vid=1641940297.1515341967&ga_sid=1515341967&ga_hid=50326500&ga_fc=1&pv=1&icsg=2&nhd=1&dssz=2&mdo=0&mso=0&u_tz=-300&u_his=1&u_java=0&u_h=768&u_w=1366&u_ah=768&u_aw=1366&u_cd=32&u_nplug=0&u_nmime=0&adx=10&ady=4761&biw=0&bih=0&abxe=1&eid=38893302%2C21061122%2C191880502%2C41667001&oid=3&nmo=1&rx=0&eae=4&fc=16&brdim=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1366%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0&vis=0&rsz=%7C%7CeEbr%7C&abl=CS&ppjl=u&pfx=0&fu=1040&bc=1&ifi=4&dtd=283. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

   Warning: :1 Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-first-hibernate-application from frame with URL https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-4699858549023382&output=html&h=280&slotname=5592503653&adk=1365123429&adf=1932081468&w=336&lmt=1515359967&loeid=38893312&format=336x280&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.javatpoint.com%2Fsteps-to-create-first-hibernate-application&ea=0&flash=0&wgl=0&adsid=NT&dt=1515341967388&bpp=3&fdt=253&idt=262&shv=r20180102&cbv=r20170110&saldr=aa&prev_fmts=160x600%2C320x100%2C320x100&correlator=6433104240641&frm=20&ga_vid=1641940297.1515341967&ga_sid=1515341967&ga_hid=50326500&ga_fc=1&pv=1&icsg=2&nhd=1&dssz=2&mdo=0&mso=0&u_tz=-300&u_his=1&u_java=0&u_h=768&u_w=1366&u_ah=768&u_aw=1366&u_cd=32&u_nplug=0&u_nmime=0&adx=10&ady=4761&biw=0&bih=0&abxe=1&eid=38893302%2C21061122%2C191880502%2C41667001&oid=3&nmo=1&rx=0&eae=4&fc=16&brdim=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1366%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0&vis=0&rsz=%7C%7CeEbr%7C&abl=CS&ppjl=u&pfx=0&fu=1040&bc=1&ifi=4&dtd=283. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
   ```
2. If I run without any delay, i.e.

   ```
   wkhtmltopdf  https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-first-hibernate-application  app.pdf
   ```

   the created pdf file only contains part of the code snippets. Event if I download the complete webpage in google chrome web browser, and then use wkhtmltopdf to convert it to pdf file, I still have the same problem.

I was wondering if there is some way to print the webpage to pdf without the above problems?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 as my OS.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the code snippets rendered by Javascript?

Comment: The code snippets correspond to the elements `<div class="codeblock">`. I am not sure which framework it is.

Comment: I mean, if you disabled Javascript, for example, just curl the page, you wouldn't see the full code blocks?

Comment: You can print to pdf in chrome as an alternative, no?

Comment: (1) Do you mean first download the webpage by curl, and then use wkhtmltopdf to convert the downloaded html file to pdf? What is the command of using curl? (2) I can print it to pdf in chrome, but the pdf file will not have bookmarks/outlines, or am I missing something? wkhtmltopdf can create pdf file with bookmarks/outlines from html file

Comment: I've not used this utility, so I'm not sure it's limitations. I'm asking if curl displays the code blocks, you don't need to write it to a file, necessarily. I'm just wondering if it's javascript loading them, or just the CSS formatting displays them

Comment: Thanks. Could you let me know the curl command that I can run?

Comment: `curl <address>` is the syntax... https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html